# My CSS @keyframes (moving images & appear) isn't working

Tags: html, css

The two @keyframes don't work.

I'm trying to have a group of images of coffee, slide in from the right of the screen and go left and in the middle, a piece of text to appear saying " Check out our new additions to our menu".

The two @keyframes worked temporarily at first, but then stopped, and I didn't change anything, so I don't know why they would have stopped

```css
#slider .container {
  position: relative;
  top: -550px;
  left: -1px;
  background: #535a6c;
  width: 1210px;
  height: 290px;
}

#slider .container img {
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left: 190px;
  top: 50px;
  animation: moving images 3s infinite;
}

#slider .container ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider .container ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

details details details. details details details details details details details details details .animatedText {
  color: #e3c383;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 2.3px;
  text-align: justify;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  top: -830px;
  left: -190px;
  position: relative;
  animation: appear 3s infinite;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.animatedText a {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #e3c383;
  animation: appear 3s infinite;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.animatedtext a:hover {
  color: rgba(170, 122, 70, 0.99);
}

@keyframes moving images {
  to {
    transform: translate(-200px)
  }
  from {
    transform: translate(1000px)
  }
}

@keyframes appear {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="slider">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li class="1">
        <img src="https://thumbsdreamstime.com/b/
                           irish-coffee-glass-isolated-white 
                           background-made-whiskey-light-cream-   
                           76284912.jpg" alt="COCO 4 U Drink Option">
      </li>

      <li class="2">
        <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/ 
                           imagestore/imagestore1606/
                           imagestore160600277/57801349-
                           iced-coffee-mocha-in-glass-with-cream-  
                           isolated-on-white-background-Stock-   
                           Photo.jpg" alt="COCO 4 U Drink Option">
      </li>

      <li class="3">
        <img src="https://previews.123rf.com
                           /images/baibaz/baibaz1504/
                           baibaz150400016/39092393-iced-coffee-   
                           covered-with-whipped-cream-in- 
                    plastic-glass-isolated-on-white-     
                           background-Stock-  
                           Photo.jpg" alt="COCO 4 U Drink Option">
      </li>

      <li class="4">
        <img src="https://encrypted   
                           tbn0.gstatic.com/images?  
                           q=tbn:ANd9GcQw02NI5xexM02vb80W  
                           0KS0dMhVrHPjpgy2QG6oCkkdca_zwDG" alt="COCO 4 U Drink Option">
      </li>

      <li class="5">
        <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/
                           coffee-latte glass-mug-steamed-milk- 
                           head-milk-banding-blending-body- 
                           white background-37395333.jpg" alt="COCO 4 U Drink Option">
      </li>

      <li class="6">
        <img src="https://www.colourbox.com/preview/
                           18200442-glass-coffee-frappe-    
                           isolated.jpg" alt="COCO 4 U Drink Option">
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>
</section>



<div class="menu_teaser">
  <h3 class="animatedText">CHECK OUT OUR THE ADDITIONS TO OUR MENU
    <a href="ourmenu.html"><strong> HERE</strong>.
                 </a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what the code is intended to do. Can you help clarify?
 What is `details details details...` in the CSS? Also, the [`animation-name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-name) cannot contain spaces.

Comment: wtf are those details details details in your CSS... anyway, you have actual spaces in your img sources, and spaces in your animation names... that won't work. And your "appear" animation goes from opacity 1 to opacity 0, which at least in my country mean things **dis**appear.

Comment: Okay so firstly, I got really annoyed at the editor looking for more details , so I just put them in to see if they'd post it and that time it did, so I wasn't able to edit it after it posted. Secondly, thank you very much for your responses I will try your suggestions now and thirdly can animation name contain (-) 's then?

Comment: @Facundo,@Showdev I tried what ye said and it still isn't working any other ideas

Comment: @AdamOCeallaigh please update the snippet or link to a jsfiddle or codepen with the code.. at least with the images url correctly, so we can work from there

Comment: #slider .container img{
 height: 170px;
 margin: 10px;
 position: relative;
 left: 190px;
 top: 50px;
 animation: moving-images 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes moving-images{
 to{ transform: translate(-200px)}
 from{transform: translate(1000px)}
}

Comment: .animatedText {
 color:#e3c383;
 font-family: "Arial",sans-serif;
 font-size: 28px;
 line-height: 2.3px;
 text-align: justify;
 float: right;
 margin-left:10px;
 padding: 0; 
 top: -830px;
 left: -190px;
 position: relative;
 animation: appear 3s infinite;
    font-weight: bold;
    transform-origin: center bottom;

}

.animatedText a{
 font-size: 28px;
 color: #e3c383;
 animation: appear 3s infinite ;
 font-weight: bold;
 transform-origin: center bottom; 
}

@keyframes appear{
 to{ opacity: 1;}
 from{ opacity: 0;}
}

Comment: @FacundoCorradini,@showdev  https://codepen.io/Adamoc/pen/rpdQER